# HOCON config file dynamic substitution

Tags: kotlin, hocon

I'm using HOCON to configure log messages and I'm looking for a way to substitute placeholder values dynamically.

I know that `${?PLACEHOLDER}` will read an environment variable and returns an empty string when the `PLACEHOLDER` environment variable doesn't exist.

## Example

This is an example of what I had in mind:

(I'm using `config4k` to load HOCON )

```
data class LogMessage(val message: String, val code: String)

fun getMessage(key: String, placeholderValues: Array<String> = arrayOf()): LogMessage {
    val config = ConfigFactory.parseString("MY_LOG_MESSAGE {code = ABC-123456, message = My log message with dynamic value %0% and another dynamic value %1% }")

    val messageObject = config.extract<LogMessage>(key)
    var message = messageObject.message

    placeholderValues.forEachIndexed { placeholderIndex, value ->
        message = message.replace("%$placeholderIndex%", value)
    }

    return messageObject.copy(message = message)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {    
    println(getMessage("MY_LOG_MESSAGE", arrayOf("value 1", "value 2")))

    // prints: LogMessage(message=My log message with dynamic value value 1 and another dynamic value value 2, code=ABC-123456)
}
```

Even though this works, it doesn't look like the best solution and I assume there already is a solution for this.

Could someone tell me if there is a built-in solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first.
HOCON is just a glorified JSON format.
config4k is just a wrapper.
All your work is being done by [Typesafe Config](https://github.com/lightbend/config), as you've probably noticed.
And judging by their documentation and code, they support placeholders only from withing the file, or from the environment:

> This library limits itself to config files. If you want to load config
>   from a database or something, you would need to write some custom
>   code.

But for what you're doing, simple `String.format()` should be enough:

```
fun interpolate(message: String, vararg args: Any) = String.format(message, *args)

println(interpolate("My message was %s %s %s %s", "a", 1, 3.32, true)) 
// My message was a 1 3.32 true
```

Notice that you can use `*` to destructure your array.